# Haskell infinite loop

Tags: loops, haskell

I am implementing a calculator in Haskell to brush up on the language but I am hitting a snag in my main when I want it to enter an infinite loop until the user inputs `q`. 
Heres my main let me know if you see what I'm doing wrong and  ill also post my error

```
error: No instances for (Floating (IO a0), Read (IO a0))
      arising from a use of `compute'
    Possible fix:
      add instance declarations for (Floating (IO a0), Read (IO a0))
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: compute e
    In the expression:
      do { compute e;
           evaluate_input }
    In an equation for `evaluate_expression':
        evaluate_expression e
          = do { compute e;
                 evaluate_input }
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `compute`?

Comment: At some point you are trying to `read` a value of type `IO x`, probably in the function you didn't bother to post. The good news is that GHC should tell you *exactly* which line causes the error :)

Comment: @us2012
compute :: (Read a, Num a, Fractional a, Floating a) => String -> a

Comment: I edited the code above and put the compute function at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your do-statement

```
 compute e 
 evaluate_input
```

both function need to be of the same monadic type, in here `IO` (declared by `evaluate_input :: IO ()`). So GHC now can expect that `compute` is a function that takes the `String` e and returns an `IO a0` (`== a`). Yet, it could not find any `a0` so that `IO a0` is an instance of `Floating` or `Read`, which `a` must be.

I'd assume that you want to output the result of the computation (and `a` is an instance of `Show` rather than `Read`), so use

```
do
 putStrLn . show $ compute e
 evaluate_input
```